# Remove characters when creating MySql view

Tags: mysql

I create a view in MySQL like this:

```
Select projects.col_82 As Hunter
```

( projects.col_82 is VARCHAR(255) ) However this column has unwanted characters in the beginning that I want to remove.

In the database the field could be stored like this :

```
nnnn:Text
```

I want to strip the nnnn's from the string - only keeping the text AFTER the colon.

The length of nnnn can vary, but I only need the characters after the column.

So if the database has the following values:

```
26152:One

34:Two

23343:Three
```

I want the field in my view to be

```
One

Two

Three
```

How can I do this when creating my view?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the view to the following

```
Select substring_index(projects.col_82,':',-1) As Hunter

Where projects.col_82 is VARCHAR(255)
```